# I am trying to include a PHP file into another file, from different folders

Tags: php

am trying to include a file that is in a folder into another file that is within a different folder in php

```
include ('inc/config.php'); //from config folder
include('design/footer.php');// from design folder
```

including these two files into admin.php that belongs to admin folder.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: can your share snapshot of your directory structure?

Comment: Use full path is best practice, so that we could have a chance to change in single place. `$varRootBasePath = dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
if($varRootBasePath == ''){ $varRootBasePath = '/home/product/newproduct'; }
//HEADER INCLUDE
include_once($varRootBasePath."/conf/config.inc");`

Comment: I think the problem is that the include is working properly......

Comment: if admin folder is sibling to inc and design folder you have to simply go to parent folder like: `../`, where `include` function lookup for files is documented read it: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 0):

So what is your problem? Attach your file structure here, so people can gues what you want.

Comment: This should be in comment not in answer

Comment: It says that I must have 50 reputation to comment others posts